# Update Array of Objects based on Array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to update an array of objects. The `active` key will be set to true based on user's selection or the array of strings.

For an instance, on selecting `ABC, DEF`, the `active` key will be set to `true` for these two Ids.

```
const defaultArray = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "DEF",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "GHI",
    "value": "3"
  }
]
```

```
const selectedArray = [
  "ABC",
  "DEF"
]
```

So now I need to create a new Array based on the default array and assign `active=true` only for array of string in `selecetedArray`.

Result will look like

```
const newArray = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "DEF",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "GHI",
    "value": "3"
  }
]
```

I tried.

```
const arrCopy = [...defaultArray]
arrCopy.forEach(x => x.active = false)
arrCopy.forEach(x => {
    if(selectedArray.includes(x.name))
        x.active =  true
})

console.log(arrCopy)
```

The above code works, but is there any more standard way to achieve the same. thanks

Comment: pay attention that item of defaultArray also changed in your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need two loops to achieve that, you can directly use `map` method on the `defaultArray`.

```
defaultArray.map(x => ({...x, active: selectedArray.includes(x.name)}))
```

```js
const defaultArray = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "DEF",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "GHI",
    "value": "3"
  }
]
const selectedArray = [
  "ABC",
  "DEF"
]

const newArray = defaultArray.map(x => ({...x, active: selectedArray.includes(x.name)}))

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through your array of objects & see if selectedArray `includes` the specified `name` attribute from each object and set the result to `active` flag, like the following -

```js
const defaultArray = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "DEF",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "GHI",
    "value": "3"
  }
];

const selectedArray = [
  "ABC",
  "DEF"
];

const arrCopy = [...defaultArray];
arrCopy.forEach(x => x.active =  selectedArray.includes(x.name));

console.log(arrCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can remove this line :

```
arrCopy.forEach(x => x.active = false)
```

and do it like this :

```
arrCopy.forEach(x => {
    if(selectedArray.includes(x.name)){
        x.active =  true}
    else{
       x.active =  false
     }    
})
```

you can write a function to do achieve that goal if this piece would be repeated in your code

Answer (score 0):

Adding new arguments to the `checkActive`function will check in the object if the name exists.

The function is:

```
function checkActive(...args){
    return  newArray.map(obj=>{
         if(args.includes(obj.name)){
              obj.active = true
         }else{
              obj.active = false
         }
        return obj
      })

}
console.log(checkActive("ABC","DEF"))
```